# how to change the circular progress indicator after loading the data Flutter

Tags: flutter

the circular progress indicator dont disappear after loading the data .

this is my code where im using the progress indicator

and when i reach the end of the grid view it should load the other data but

the progress indicator makes the same thing it loads and dont disappear after getting data .

i tried to make a boolean isLoading and tried to change it true or false but couldnt find the place where i can do this

```
int pageNumber = 1;
String filterName = '';

class ShowsListDesign extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowsListDesignState createState() => _ShowsListDesignState();
}

class _ShowsListDesignState extends State<ShowsListDesign> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  ServicesClass service = ServicesClass();
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
controller.addListener(listenScrolling);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
  future: service.getFilms('posts/$pageNumber/$filterName'),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: [
              GridView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                gridDelegate: const             
SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                  maxCrossAxisExtent: 250,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 24,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 24,
                  childAspectRatio: (3 / 5),
                ),
                controller: controller,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return FilmsCard(
                    image: snapshot.data[index]['thumbnailUrl'],
                    title: snapshot.data[index]['title'],
                    year: snapshot.data[index]['year'],
                  );
                },
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  scrollUp();
                },
                elevation: 24,
                backgroundColor: PRIMARY,
                child: const Text(
                  'Scroll Up',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  void scrollUp() {
    const double start = 0;
    controller.animateTo(start,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1, milliseconds: 50),
        curve: Curves.easeIn);
  }

  void listenScrolling() {
    if (controller.position.atEdge) {
      final isTop = controller.position.pixels == 0;
      if (isTop) {
      } else {
        setState(() {
          pageNumber++;

          ShowsListDesign();
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please, paste your code here in order to give you a proper help

Comment: Can you show ```listenScolling```

Comment: i updated the post check the code

Comment: Just an idea. Try to remove listener and see if that helps. To my mind, setState is being called often which causes to rebuild your widget and with that, service is being called every time.

Comment: the problem was there before i put the listener

Comment: Did you try  to create a function outside the Widget ```....Widget build(BuildContext context) {....```. Adding it above and using setState(), will repaint the area without the loading animation.

Comment: no i didnt . cant u tell me how ?

Comment: It is possible to get errors or no data on future, it will be better with handling those states.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get errors or no data on future, it will be better with handling those states.

```dart
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
    return const Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  } else if (snapshot.hasData &&
      snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: [...],
    );
  } else if (!snapshot.hasData &&
      snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    return const Text("couldn't find any data");
  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return Text("${snapshot.error}");
  } else {
    return const Text(" any other");
  }
},
```

More about [FutureBuilder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: when i open the films tab it may tell me 'couldnt find any data ' but there is a data but it didnt get loaded yet , when i go to another tab and get back again the data appears

Comment: Check the future `service.getFilms` return type.  And can you  try removing `setState(())` statements from this widget.

Comment: Future<List?> getFilms(String api) {}

Comment: delete the setState from the scroll listener ? how can i load the nxt page of data then ?

Comment: I will prefer parent widgets  to load data on `initState` then pass data on TabbarView.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use FutureBuilder if it's not a one page load. Try this:
(I don't understand your scrolling mechanism though), also call super.initState when you override

```dart
String filterName = '';

class ShowsListDesign extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowsListDesignState createState() => _ShowsListDesignState();
}

class _ShowsListDesignState extends State<ShowsListDesign> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  ServicesClass service = ServicesClass();
  bool isLoading = false;

// New
  int pageNumber = 1;
  List? data;

  Future<void> load() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
     
    });
    data = await service.getFilms('posts/1/$filterName');
    setState(() => isLoading = false);
    
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
// Make sure you call super.initState() when you override
    controller.addListener(listenScrolling);
    super.initState();
    load();
    
    
  }

// Also call dispose to remove listener
@override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(listener);
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(
  
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    if (data != null) {
      return Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: [
              GridView.builder(
                itemCount: data!.length,
                gridDelegate: const             
SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                  maxCrossAxisExtent: 250,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 24,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 24,
                  childAspectRatio: (3 / 5),
                ),
                controller: controller,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return FilmsCard(
                    image: data![index]['thumbnailUrl'],
                    title: data![index]['title'],
                    year: data![index]['year'],
                  );
                },
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  scrollUp();
                },
                elevation: 24,
                backgroundColor: PRIMARY,
                child: const Text(
                  'Scroll Up',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  void scrollUp() {
    const double start = 0;
    controller.animateTo(start,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1, milliseconds: 50),
        curve: Curves.easeIn);
  }

  Future<void> listenScrolling() async {
// Change this depending on the scrolling works ?!
    if (controller.position.pixels == controller.position.maxScrollExtent && data != null) {
        List new_data = await service.getFilms('posts/${pageNumber + 1}/$filterName');
        data.addAll(new_data);
        setState(() {
          
          pageNumber++;

        });
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ok got it , but the code is giving invalid array length error when i scroll to the end ,i will try to fix this

Comment: I edited ```data?.length``` to ```data!.length```

Comment: Error: XMLHttpRequest error.

Comment: That would be from the service.getFilms API; you can use a try catch to handle the error